# contract function invoked by web3py without error but have no effect (ganache local network)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ganache, web3py

compiled code by py-solc-x, then deployed it to the ganache local network using web3py api.
first, call a get_balance function and it return as expected.
second, call the transfer function and it return without error, but the balance have not changed when I call get_balance later.
try to call transfer by sending a raw transaction but it still no effect...

metacoin.sol (provided by truffle doc)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MetaCoin {

    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint _value);    

    constructor() public {
        balances[msg.sender] = 10000;
    }

    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) public returns(bool sufficient) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= amount)
            return false;

        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);   
        return true;
    }

    function get_balance(address account) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[account];
    }
}
```

interacting.py

```
    # deploy contract by w3.eth.accounts[0]
    # the balance of the accounts[0] is 10000 (call get_balance() return 10000)
    # then transfer 1000 from accounts[0] to accounts[1]

    deployed_address = '0x538574C591F6e01E22eFa951153a29e6Fc505735'
    contract = w3.eth.contract(address=HexBytes(deployed_address), abi=abi)
    tx_hash = contract.functions.transfer(w3.eth.accounts[1], 1000).transact()
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
    print(tx_receipt.contractAddress)

    balance = contract.functions.get_balance(w3.eth.accounts[0]).call()
    print(balance)    
    # still 10000, expect 9000.
```

the transfer transaction looks good.
both gas/gasPrice and dynamic fee transaction have been tried but the balance still the same.
it's the problem from the ganache local network setting ? or some required configured steps I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the transaction went through

```
assert tx_receipt.status == 1
```

Also if Ganache does not work then try [Ethereum Tester based tests. Example token tests here](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/master/tests/test_token.py#L68).

Comment: thanks a lot, the tx status have been checked and it's ok. I also tried it at ropsten but still. Surprisingly i have figured out which part went wrong: i found the erc20 abi file at the project 
 directory you provided(web3-ethereum-defi/eth_defi/abi/ERC20MockDecimals.json), I use it to replace my abi file, and it works!!! at ganache local network. the sample code  or compilation should be the problem thogh it was totally follow the web3py documentation, thanks again.